# Who ruled first, “girls” or “boys”?

Tags: american-english, phrase-origin, catch-phrases, slogan

A recent [ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/224768/what-does-boys-rule-girls-drool-mean) contains a catchphrase which is utterly novel to me.

> Boys rule, girls drool

Wanting to know more, I searched online and found a female variant.

> Girls rule and boys drool

The meaning here, interestingly, appears to be quite different. *Girls* who are physically attractive  make *boys* drool because their mouths, figuratively speaking, are open in admiration.

Not being American and not remembering if this slogan was used in the UK during the 1970s or 80s,  I posted a comment asking @James K which version was the older: the *boys rule* or *girls rule*.

Unfortunately, I never got a reply, all the comments were swiftly deleted, so here I am asking on EL&U.

The original slogan, from what I could gather, appears to be the "girls rule". The earliest instance in print I found was **October 1997** from the magazine *[American Motorcyclist](https://books.google.it/books?id=K_YDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22girls%20rule%20boys%20drool%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0ieXSkdDkAhXIJlAKHejpAAcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22girls%20rule%20boys%20drool%22&f=false)* Oct 1997

> Fifteen-year-old Stephanie “Stevie” Welch is waiting while her father readies her Yamaha YZ125. A large banner spanning the front of her family's race transporter takes a good-natured jab at her male competition: “#43, Stevie Welch–**Girls Rule, Boys Drool**.”

1. Which slogan came first: "Girls rule, the boys drool" or "Boys rule, the girls drool"? What is its origins?
2. Does inverting the gender change the meaning significantly?
3. Is either one used in the UK or in Australia?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98681/discussion-on-question-by-mari-lou-a-who-ruled-first-girls-or-boys).

Comment: Any evidence that this is a common phrase? I searched Google ngram with wildcars but it didn't really turn up anything resembling the *boys / girls drool*, let alone the whole phrase.

Comment: @JJJ I've not heard it used myself, but if it's commonly heard and used in schoolyards it doesn't surprise me that its appearance is comparatively rare in *books*. But the simple fact that no one has said the slogan is unfamiliar, see ELL's relevant post, and no one else on EL&U is pretty telling. I also note that it appears on a Reddit page (https://www.reddit.com/r/unpopularopinion/comments/9zsx44/i_feel_that_the_girls_rule_is_destroying_the/) and also note the info about Amazon selling merchandise with that slogan.

Comment: @JJJ By the way, what difference would it have made if the slogan was comparatively rare? is asking a question about an uncommon catchphrase off-topic? Is that why you voted to close it? A question that shows effort, research and is about contemporary English. What is unclear about it? Could you please explain?

Comment: If only we could go back to those playground (pre-dating the internet) and survey which catchphrase was more common when. Now it's just a competition of who can find the earliest example in writing, even though [*rule* meaning *"to dominate, prevail"* has been around since 1874](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rule).

Comment: @JJJ Yu didn't answer my question. I think maybe you spend too much time on Politics.SE. (*wink*)

Comment: I spent enough time here to have come across it in the close vote queue. ;) And like I said, I'm not voting for a lack of effort but because I think this question will gather primarily opinion-based responses. Either we're getting responses saying they heard the *girls drool* at Eton in 60s (like I did), someone who's heard the other variant at some point in time or we're getting written responses where it's just a race to the earliest date. So for that reason, in my judgment (and I'm sure others will disagree) it's POB.

Comment: And should you have spent more time on Politics.SE you may have been more familiar with former school pupils inventing things about their time at school to further their interests now. Ranging from the fields of wheat to erotic encounters with pigs, or as they say [in politics (Y,PM)](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=yes-prime-minister-1986&episode=s02e01) *"It is characteristic of committee decisions that every member has a vivid recollection of them and that every member's recollection differs from every other member's."*, alas, we have no minutes.

Comment: @JJJ How is asking  its origins, and whether it is familiar in the UK and in Australia POB? The focus is not just on which version came first, despite the title, it's really asking  **if users are familiar with it and what more can they tell me**. The thing is if I had included that as a question, it would have been closed for being ***too broad***. Ah, the irony...

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to rephrase it in a way that you ask primarily about origins, with a focus on geographical area? My uneducated guess would be that it has English origins, because (in my highly skewed perception) they'd speak more about *boys and girls*, though that may be a more recent perception. I think that way you get more of a closed question that isn't broad and can be followed-up once you learn more about geographical origins (e.g. maybe an historical argument that puts it into place, which may be on topic on History.SE).

Comment: @JJJ  It's been edited and it was clarified after Ibf posted, I mentioned that I had never heard it used in the UK and I gave a specific time period (70s- 80s) I added the link to the ELL question which was inspired by a line said in the  American movie, *Dumb and dumber* (2014), so the question is well-supported, clear and not just POB if you don't focus solely on the title.

Comment: Well, I'll retract my close vote. ;)

Comment: @JJJ noted and appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Which slogan came first: "Girls rule the boys drool" or "Boys rule the girls drool"?*

From [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=4k4Ma-63lKgC&q=%22boys%20rule%20girls%20drool%22&dq=%22boys%20rule%20girls%20drool%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwil19iPotHkAhUQHqwKHTArDRIQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg):

**Minding the Body: Women Writers on Body and Soul**:  Doubleday, **1994** - Social Science

> Found inside - Page 11 ... I watched an enthusiastic little boy leap out of the swimming pool and run shrieking around its perimeter, shouting “**Boys rule, girls drool**!”

And again from [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22girls%20rule%20boys%20drool%22&client=firefox-b-1-d&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNT6fa2tChea5jyUebRAEDaDTKZAcg:1568496830483&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh2qWDotHkAhUHUK0KHXouC3UQpwUIIg&biw=1261&bih=672&dpr=4):

**American Motorcyclist** - Oct **1997** (your citation)

> Found inside - Page 36 Fifteen-year-old Stephanie "Stevie" Welch is
>   waiting while her father readies her Yamaha YZ125. A large banner
>   span- ning the front of her family's race transporter takes a
>   good-natured jab at her male competition: "#43, Stevie Welch - **Girls
>   Rule, Boys Drool**."

So technically ( by a couple of years), **boys rule girls drool** wins in earliest usage, acknowledging the limitations of simple google book searches.

*Are their meanings different? Am I right in surmising that both catchphrases are politically incorrect nowadays?*

Yes they are different in that in one saying, boys rule the roost and in the other saying the girls rule.  Depending on one's position in life, vulnerability ( say a politician v. a comic ) etc ... one would use with caution.

*Is either one used in the UK or in Australia?*

As a native speaker of AmE, I cannot answer this question

Comment: See also [_Bulletin_](https://books.google.com/books?id=C4aaV9OKDr0C&q=%22boys+drool+girls%22&dq=%22boys+drool+girls%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOi5y9v9HkAhWTr54KHU0qC3QQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg), volume 57 (1995): "As Nick writes, 'we've taken advice from the famous Prescott (“81, but good enough to have been '83 if he only waited a bit) family motto—boys drool—girls rule.' With the two beautiful daughters, Maria & Nick must feel like the king and queen."

Comment: I've modified the second question, it doesn't begatively affect your answer, only the quotation you cited.